# Hide thumb on Material Slider

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-slider

I'm migrating from `AppCompatSeekBar` to `material.slider.Slider`

Removing the thumb on the SeekBar was easy using `splitTrack="false"`.

How can I achieve the same with the Slider?

Comment: Not sure about what you are looking for. The splitTrack attribute whether to split the track and leave a gap for the thumb drawable. In the Slider there is a gap between the thumb and the track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the attributes:

- `app:haloRadius`
- `app:thumbRadius`

To avoid the halo you can use `app:haloRadius`. Use `10dp` as the `thumbRadius`:

```
        <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
            app:haloRadius="10dp"
            ../>
```

[image]

You can also remove the thumb and the halo using the attribute `app:thumbRadius="0dp"`

```
       <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
            app:thumbRadius="0dp"
            app:haloRadius="0dp"
            ..../>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about setting `0dp` to `app:thumbRadius` and/or `app:haloRadius`?

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
    app:thumbRadius="0dp"
    app:haloRadius="0dp"
    />
```